# What is the correct regex for a 24 hour clock with alphabet support (java)

Tags: java, regex

Here is the program:

```
public static boolean hasValidLengthAndSeparator(String s) {
  boolean answer = false;
  String text = s;
  String pattern = "([01a]?[0-9]+[b]?|2[0-3]+?):[c]?[d]?[0-5]?[0-9]?";

  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  Matcher m = r.matcher(text);


  if (m.find()) {
      answer = true;
  }
  else {
      answer = false;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

when I do the tests it fails for "1:30" (it returns true, but its not suppose to) how do I fix it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. `1:30` matches because `[0-9]` matches `1`, `[0-5]` matches `3` and `[0-9]` matches `0`

Comment: yes but its suppose to be in the form of "ab:cd", where a is a number 0 or 1, b is a number from 0-9, c is a number from 0-5, and d is a number from 0-9. and needs to match "ab:cd" as well.

Comment: So `(?:[01a][\db]|2[0-3b]):[0-5c][\dd]`?

Comment: thanks for the help! but it was not correct. I had to modify it to allow "29:99" type times as well. The fix was (?:[01a][\\db]|2[0-9b]):[0-9c][\\dd]

Comment: by the way how do I put this as solved? First time using stack overflow.

Comment: Post an answer and explain the pattern. A good idea is to add a http://regex101.com demo link

Comment: Emm, could some1 explain what is 24 hour clock with alphabet support?

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER: `(?:[01a][\\db]|2[0-9b]):[0-9c][\\dd]`

The regex was suppose to allow a string (s) to validate to true if the length was 5 and the third character is a colon, and false otherwise.

By using this tester:

```
@Test
  public void test09_hasValidLengthAndSeparator() {
    final String[] VALID = {"01:30", "ab:cd", "29:99"};
    for (int i = 0; i < VALID.length; i++) {
      String s = VALID[i];
      String error = 
          String.format("regextest.hasValidLengthAndSeparator(s) returned false for s = %s", s);
      assertTrue(error, lab0.hasValidLengthAndSeparator(s));
    }
    final String[] NOT_VALID = {"", "1:30", "01,23", "29:9"};
    for (int i = 0; i < NOT_VALID.length; i++) {
      String s = NOT_VALID[i];
      String error = 
          String.format("regextest.hasValidLengthAndSeparator(s) returned true for s = %s", s);
      assertFalse(error, regextest.hasValidLengthAndSeparator(s));
    }
  }
```